# When do I collect my luggage?

Tags: luggage, ams, sfo

I will be flying from Lithuania to Amsterdam with a stop by at some other country. From Amsterdam, I will fly to San Francisco which will be connected to the other city. Will I need to collect my luggage at the city I will be stopping by, or only in Amsterdam and after in the USA? Flying first time and am very confused.

Comment: the answer to your question depends on things you haven't provided. Please edit your question. What airline are you flying? what is the "some other country" and how long will you "stop by" there?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please tell us all the stops/cities; that will make it easer to answer you. If you add the airlines, that will help too.

Answer (score 2):

If your itinerary is booked on one ticket (you bought all the flights at the same time in a single purchase), and you have less than twenty-four hours in each of the cities on your journey, then your bags will automatically go as far as San Francisco. There you will collect them for a customs inspection, and then drop them again at a special bag drop belt, for their onward journey to your final city.

When you check your bags in, you will be told where to collect them next.

Comment: Note that OTAs typically join several bookings into one. If that's the case then you will need to pick the baggage at the intermediate airport. I just want to remark that "single ticket" is not the same as "single booking".

Comment: I find both of your sentences to be incorrect. I always ask when I check in a bag where I will be seeing it next. Sometimes they tell me I have to pick it up along the way, but only because I asked. They weren't going to otherwise. And you can buy tickets from Expedia etc that combine airlines who do not interline, so you will have to pick up and recheck the bag. Without knowing the airlines the passenger is using you really can't have this level of confidence

Comment: @KateGregory Excluding "hacker fares", which are not single tickets and should be clearly marked as such, can you give an example of such a ticket? IATA is pretty strict about this.